# Rebasing QA branch off of main instead of develop

Tags: git, git-rebase

Initially in my workflow, I had the following branch structure (`develop` off of `main`, feature branches off of `develop`):

```
main ---\
         \-- develop --\
                        \-- feature --
```

Later on, we decided to add a `qa` branch. Initially I made `qa` off of `develop`, so now the branch structure looks like this:

```
main ---\
         \-- develop --\
                        \-- qa --
                         \-- feature --
```

I want the workflow to be that we merge feature branches into `develop`, then `develop` into `qa` for testing, then `qa` into `main` for release. For that I would need something like this:

```
main ---\
         \-- qa --\
                   \-- develop --\
                                  \-- feature --
```

How can I go from my existing structure (`qa` based off of `develop`) to the new one (`qa` based off of `main` and `develop` based off of `qa`)? I think I need to rebase but not quite sure how.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Basically your `qa` branch would be equivalent to a `release` branch in Git Flow. And in that case, what you have is already what you would want. (The middle graph would be preferred over the bottom graph.) With your current strategy, once you're happy with `qa`, deploy it to production and merge it into `main`.

Comment: @TTT so the issue with my current approach is that when I merge `develop` into `qa` to kick off a QA deployment, the entire diff ends up showing up as merge conflicts. I then need to resolve those to deploy. Then, the next merge from `develop` to `qa` goes through conflict free, but the next one after that will result in the same thing. Am I just missing a step in my workflow to avoid this?

Comment: If you go with the Git Flow idea, and consider `qa` to be like a `release` branch, then you would never actually merge `develop` into `qa`. You create `qa` from `develop`, fix it up until you are happy with it (possibly merge `qa` with fixes on it back into `develop` if you want), and then merge `qa` into `main` and `main` into `develop`. At that point you can delete the temporary `qa` branch, or leave it and reset it to be `develop` the next time you wish to test new code on it.

Comment: Note, in theory you *could* still merge `develop` into `qa` to update `qa` instead of resetting it to be `develop`, but you should *only* do it after the entire `qa` branch has already been merged back down into `develop` (or `qa` to `main` and then `main` to `develop`). That is where all conflicts should be resolved. If you do it that way it won't be possible to have conflicts merging `develop` into `qa` as it will always be a fast-forward merge, which would be identical to just resetting `qa` to `develop`.

Comment: To answer your specific question, I think the step(s) you are missing, is after you are happy with `qa`, merge it into `main` and merge `main` into `develop`- and resolve conflicts if you have any when you merge `main` into `develop`. From there the next merge of `develop` into `qa` will be fast-forward and can't possibly have conflicts. (Sorry if this sounds super complicated...it's one of the main reasons some people don't like Git Flow- due to the complexity.)

Answer (score 0):

Not commenting if any of that makes sense :) and with a bit of warning that this will only work if the commits reachable by one branch but not the other do not introduce conflicting changes, here's how `git rebase` can be used to reshape your history:

```
git rebase --onto main develop qa
git rebase qa develop
git rebase develop feature
```

It could be required to replace that last command with `git rebase --onto develop D feature` (`D` being the tip/head of the original `develop` branch, before rebasing)

You might appreciate some ASCII art goodness:

###### Initial state

```
A-B               -- master
   \     ,-G-H    -- qa
    `-C-D         -- develop
         `-E-F    -- feature
```

###### rebase --onto main develop qa

This one is trivial, it simply recreates both commits on top of master/B.

```
   ,-G'-H'        -- qa
A-B               -- master
   \
    `-C-D         -- develop
         `-E-F    -- feature
```

###### rebase qa develop

This will recreate develop's commit on top of qa/H'. Note that the original C and D commits are still reachable through ref `feature`, thus part of the history of the feature branch.

```
   ,-G'-H'        -- qa
A-B      \        -- master
   \      `-C'-D' -- develop
    `-C-D
         `-E-F    -- feature
```

###### rebase develop feature

This should automatically detect that C and D are already contained in the new upstream as C' and D' and skip applying them. If the automatic detection does not work, see above for an alternative command.

Once the `feature` ref has been moved, the original C and D commits become unreachable.

```
   ,-G'-H'               -- qa
A-B      \               -- master
          `-C'-D'        -- develop
                `-E'-F'  -- feature
```

Of course all commits will be assigned new commit ids (the original commits are gone, but new commits are created in their place).